# Accessing Graph API's through delegated permissions of service account without user interaction

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm looking for the best approach to allow an app to access the Graph API's through a service account.

The idea is to grant delegated permissions to the Graph API's for that app which would then be restricted further by the access of the service account that is used in the app. The catch is that no interaction should be required on the service account.

E.g.: I want a developer to create any type of app to access the Graph API but only manage resources that his service account is granted access to. I don't want him to be able to manage all AAD groups for example, but only the AAD groups where his service account has ownership of.

Any guidance to get me started with a demo? I've been searching for tutorials and articles but none of them seem to match my requirements.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment I don't think you can do this.
If you do client credential authentication (client id + secret/certificate),
application permissions apply.
Delegated permissions only apply when a user is involved.
So the only way to currently limit the scope is to do the calls on behalf of a user.

Of course you can still automate it mostly.
One way is to have the developer authenticate with their account once.
Your app should then receive a refresh token for that user,
which it can then use to get new access tokens as needed to make the calls as user at any time it wants.

Now of course the only issue with refresh tokens is that they can go stale or get revoked.
The developer would have to authorize the app again.
If it is business-critical that this kind of situation does not occur,
then you must use app permissions (which are org-wide, all groups etc.).

Comment: Hi @juunas, that makes sense. But how would you see this in practice? What OAuth flow would you recommend? The goal is ofcourse to build business-critical applications so refresh tokens that can no longer request a new access token is indeed something to avoid. What measures can be taken to avoid refresh tokens from being unable to request new access tokens?

Comment: If I remember correctly, a password reset is one of the things that invalidates all refresh tokens for that user.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest using the refresh token daily and replace the old refresh token with the new refresh token returned. That keeps it from going stale.

Comment: thanks, I'll see how I can address that programmatically. Concerning the OAuth 2.0 flows: if my users are authenticating through WS-Federation (SSO), does that prevent me from using the v2 endpoint as it does not support WS-Federation or is that just for the app?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. You mean they authenticate with WS-Fed to other apps? In that case it makes no difference. Every app can choose what protocol and endpoint they want to use.

Comment: All users authenticate with WS-Federation to AAD using a 3rd party IDP (federated domain).

Comment: Okay, that shouldn't matter for your app. Your app can still use OAuth or OpenID Connect to talk with AAD.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service).

> Some apps call Microsoft Graph with their own identity and not on
> behalf of a user. In many cases, these are background services or
> daemons that run on a server without the presence of a signed-in user.
>
> ...
>
> #### Authentication and authorization steps
>
> The basic steps required to configure a service and get a token from
> the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint that your service can use to call Microsoft
> Graph under its own identity are:
>
> 1. Register your app.
> 2. Configure permissions for Microsoft Graph on your app.
> 3. Get administrator consent.
> 4. Get an access token.
> 5. Use the access token to call Microsoft Graph.

The critical bit being the configuration of permissions. Probably need to dig into the [permissions reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference) to see if it provides the granularity you need.

> #### 2. Configure permissions for Microsoft Graph
>
> For apps that call Microsoft Graph under their own identity, Microsoft
> Graph exposes application permissions. ... You pre-configure the
> application permissions your app needs when you register your app.

Comment: Hi @'James Wood', that was already more or less clear to me. The problem is that we don't want to dish out application permissions as there is no scoping on them. The developer would have to make sure the scoping is done programmatically and we would have to put our trust in that...

Answer (score 1):

Just for the reference even if its a years old question. There is a ID Token now which will give scopes based on the **App roles**. Every developer can have its own scope and based on that you can control which developer can access which resource. This means that you would basically have to write a proxy that would filter out developer X trying to connect to resource Y based on the claims in **ID Token**.

[image]

After defining the roles you can assign a specific user to a role by going into **Enterprise Applications** -> **You App Name** -> **Users and Groups** -> **Add user/group**

[image]

Then simply assign a user to a role. Also make sure that you check **ID Token** in applications configuration.

[image]

To obtain the **ID Token** use hybrid flow which is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-id-token-as-well-or-hybrid-flow)